# Find a nonsingular matrix P given that A is similar to a Jordan matrix

Tags: matrices

Given ${\bf A}$ is similar to a Jordan matrix find a nonsingular matrix $\bf P$ such that ${\bf P}^{-1}{\bf AP}={\bf J}$

$$
{\bf A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have worked out 
$$
{\bf J}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The textbook I am using shows an example where ${\bf A}$ has one eigenvalue.  I am unsure how to apply this example to the question I have.

I am using "Matrices and Linear Transformations" by Cullen.
The example I was looking at is on page204.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ has three eigenvalues, or at least one at $1$ and one at $0$ of multiplicity 1. This tells you the general form of the Jordan form. Looking at $\ker A$ gives the $(0,1,-1)^T$ vector, $\ker (A-I)$ gives $(0,0,1)^T$, and looking at $\ker A^2$ yields the $(1,0,-1)^T$ vector. After that, it is a matter of permuting these vectors to get $P$.

Try $P=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $P^{-1} A P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
which is a Jordan form.

Comment: That second entry on the first row doesn't look compatible with Jordan form.

Comment: Oops, good catch. I'll fix it.

Comment: How do I add a hint?

Comment: What I mean is how do I add markup so that it only shows when you click/hover over the relevant region? I did a quick search but found nothing.

Comment: Click edit to see the source code of [any answer by Marvis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169270/how-do-i-form-this-equation/169272#169272) But seriously, we shouldn't be giving *all* the details of the solution..

Comment: True; I am suitably chastised...